# Simplifying inequalities with exponents

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

Here is a simple example of an inequality which I cannot get Mathematica to state as `True`:

```
FullSimplify[x^a >= 1, Assumptions -> {a > 0, x > 1}]
```

Is there a case for which the inequality is false that I haven't ruled out by the assumptions?

Answer (score 3):

I think using [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce) would be a better approach, although it's not completely straightforward:

```
Reduce[x^a < 1 && a > 0 && x > 1, Reals]
```

> False

*(updated with another approach using Resolve)*

Another possibility is to note that your question is basically the same as proving that `ForAll[{x, y}, x>1 && a>0, x^a>1]` is [`True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/True). Equivalently, we can attempt to prove that the negation, `!ForAll[{x, y}, x>1 && a>0, x^a>1]`, is [`False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/False):

```
Resolve[
    !ForAll[{x, y}, x>1 && a>0, x^a>1],
    Reals
]
```

> False

Unfortunately, a direct [`Resolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Resolve) doesn't work:

```
Resolve[
    ForAll[{x, y}, x>1 && a>0, x^a>1],
    Reals
]
```

> ForAll[{x}, x > 1 && a > 0, x^a > 1]

Comment: Why won't   Reduce[x^a > 1 && a > 0 && x > 1, Reals]    return TRUE?

Comment: Nevermind about my follow-on comment.  I understand now why Reduce has to be stated as a False statement.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Assuming[a > 0 && x > 1, 
 Reduce[x^a >= 1 && a > 0 && x > 1] // Simplify]

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply Log to both sides of the equation. This changes x^a>=1 into the equivalent inequality Log[x^a] >= Log[1]=0. FullSimplify works fine on the Log'ed version:

```
FullSimplify[Log[x^a] >= 0, {a > 0, x > 1}]
True
```